# Subscribe to a DS.Model event in controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following controller :

```
export default Controller.extend({
  /* model is an array of Posts */

  didDeletePost(post) {
    /* PROBLEM HERE : post is an InternalModel */
    this.get('model').removeObject(post);
    /* do other stuff with post */
  },

  actions: {
    markPostForDelete(post) {
      post.markForDelete(); /* starts a timer */
      post.one('didDelete', this, this.didDeletePost);
    },
    clearMarkPostForDelete(post) {
      post.clearMarkForDelete(); /* cancel a timer which will destroyRecord */
      post.off('didDelete', this, this.didDeletePost);
    }
  }
});
```

But remove the `post` from the `model` in `didDeletePost` does not work because the `post` argument is the `InternalModel`, not the `DS.Model`.

How can I achieve this ?

As it does not seem to be easy to do it like this, I guess there should be a better way to implement this kind of timer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need to remove the post from `model`.

Please check out the twiddle I provided : https://ember-twiddle.com/25de9c8d217eafe03aea874f8eefb0fd

Comment: Thank you, but this only works because you `findAll` posts, which is somewhat specific. As an example, it does not work with `query`.

Comment: @louiscoquio I updated my twiddle. It works with `query` too

Comment: You are right, sorry! It does not work in my case: I call `#toArray` in the route model in order to add some posts later from the controller. Also, I need to do some other things with the `post` in the `didDeletePost` callback.

Comment: @louiscoquio So i'm confused. Now `didDeletePost` callback would be called after the post deleted. So what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry if it's not so clear. To be simple I need to remove the post in the `controller.model` once deleted (in the controller callback `didDeletePost`), almost like in your Twiddle, but my route `model` is this one: `this.get('store').query('post', {}).then(function (posts) { returns posts.toArray(); });`

Comment: @louiscoquio I updated my answer. Please check it out (index controller)

Comment: Thank you, it works :) I accept your answer, but I'll post an issue in ember-data as I do not see any reason to have an `InternalModel` exposed like this. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

In my experience and from what others have told me, listening for events rather than calling actions/functions can leave you with very confusing chains of events (and this seems to exemplify that, at least to me).

I'd do it slightly more manually with a flag (here's an example all in the model for simplicity, tho you might need to move to the controller depending on other interactions):

```
export default DS.Model.extend({


markPostForDelete() {
    this.set('marked', true).then( () => /*function in model to start timer and then call this.deleteMarked() */);
},

clearMarkPostForDelete() {
    this.set('marked', false)
},

deleteMarked() {
    if(this.get('marked')) {
        this.destroyRecord();
    }
}
}); /* end of model */
```

Comment: In my case I need a callback in the controller, so your solution seems to wrap `Post#one('didDelete')` in `Post#markForDelete` which returns a Promise resolved once `didDelete` is sent. As it is basically the same implementation as mine, I would expect mine to work : the `post` argument in `#one` callback should be a `Post` instead of an `InternalModel`. Am I right? Do you agree?